# My Selenium script can not find the email field

Tags: selenium

I am trying to get this auto-login script working, I've already tried every type of search. What I have found out, is that if I inspect the code element of the email field, it would some times show me the whole HTML Body, and not the email field. Any help will be appriciated :)

[Error code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqTl4.png)

Comment: Hi, can you please paste your error and your code as text rather than an imagine? Also, can you please add some html source for your page so we can verify the find by is correct?

Comment: You'll most likely need a wait strategy like webdriver wait  or implicit wait, or your identifier is not accurate.. Add the details and we'll help :-)